# Compass/SASS: Know images not referenced from sprite

Tags: sass, css-sprites, compass-sass

Is there a way I can get all the images in sprite that are not referenced within css? I want to remove unused icons from my sprite.

Answer (score 0):

No. CSS preprocessor knows nothing about it's CSS output usage. Also sass instructions have no idea what comes after them and compass sprites aren't flexible enough.